# How to index an R package published in CRAN to Google Scholar?

Tags: google-scholar

I have published some R packages in CRAN; however, they do not appear in Google Scholar. Would there be any way to make my  packages visible in Google Scholar?
For example, [**knitr**](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C39&q=knitr&btnG=) appears in Google Scholar for citation entry like below:

- Xie, Y. (2013). knitr: A general-purpose package for dynamic report generation in R. R package version, 1(7), 1.

Should I manually upload any citation meta tags to Google Scholar?

Comment: Has anyone included your packages in the citations for their paper? That's where that knitr reference is coming from, it's been extracted from published papers. I don't think you can just add a reference if it hasn't been cited somewhere to google scholar. There needs to be some published article.

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

1. You can always add articles manually to google scholar.
2. If you paper gets cited by an article that is picked up by google scholar, it will appear as as cited in that article.